# can we know which is the current mode of the device i.e whether it is in Transmission mode or a reception mode?

Tags: android, sockets, networking, routes, network-programming

can we know which is the current mode of the device i.e whether it is in Transmission mode or a reception mode (Tx/Rx) ?

i'm new to android and to stack overflow, so any help is very much appreciated :)

thanks.

Comment: Transmission or reception of what?

Comment: @RaghavSood hi Raghav.  when the device is operational on a network (data/WiFi) can we know for that instant whether device is transmitting the packets (irrespective of applications ) on a port say ftp(i.e 21) or http(8080) or receiving the packets on same ports.

Comment: Not at socket level you can't.  The controller on the Wifi/NIC/whatever will know, but probably does not expose such information on the grounds that it would be stale by the time any user code got hold of it.

Comment: At the TCP level the question has no meaning, as TCP is a full-duplex protocol.

Comment: thank you for your reply.                                    so basically ports are two-way doors so we cannot actually track whether packets are arriving or leaving however. using TrafficStats(getTotalTxBytes()
Return number of bytes transmitted since device boot. and getTotalRxPackets()
Return number of packets received since device boot.) we could know how many bytes/packets are transmitted and received for a specific period of time. right?

Comment: I don't understand why you're seeking confirmation of what it already says in the documentation that you quoted.